# How to include multiple (and or) conditions in a single if statement in a shell script

Tags: shell

How to include , multiple and or conditions in a single if statement.

So far i tried :
`if [[ "$op_type" == "roll" ]] || [[("$Action" == "up" && "$Status" == "Failed")]] || [[("$Action" == "up" && "$Status" == "InProgress")]] ; then`

Comment: See https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/017

Comment: Some points to mention: You tag this question as _shell_, which means _POSIX shell_, but your code for sure is not Posix. You most likely want to write ksh or bash, or maybe zsh. Please tag the question based on the shell you are using here. Then, fix the syntax errors by pasting your code into [shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/). If afterwards there are still open questions, feel free to ask here.

Comment: @user1934428 shellcheck helped  me to fix syntax error , thank you :)

Comment: If there are still open problems, please edit your question so that your code is syntactically correct. If there is no open problem anymore, consider deleting your post.